# How can I "linkify" a non-org-mode buffer in emacs

Tags: emacs, org-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make org syntax links in any emacs buffer look like in org-mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166608/how-to-make-org-syntax-links-in-any-emacs-buffer-look-like-in-org-mode)

I would not mind using org-mode, but with non-asterisk headings.  I asked that question in [How can I use other heading styles like twiki ---+ or mediawiki == h2 == in org-mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697056/how-can-i-use-other-heading-styles-like-twiki-or-mediawiki-h2-in-org)

But the main thing I want is to "linkify" a buffer - a probably non-org-mode buffer.

E.g. make links such as [[file:/some/long/path][display name]] show just as something like "display name", and clickable.  Or just [[file:/some/path]], or the other link types org-mode supports.

Q: is there a way to get such link functionality in emacs, outside org-mode?

Comment: Actually, I know there must be, since I have been able to use iimage-mode with outline-mode, without org-mode. Hmmm....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just created an emacs minor mode that enables org style links in non-org-mode buffers. Still a work-in-progress but you can find it here: https://github.com/seanohalpin/org-link-minor-mode

BTW, this question is a duplicate of [How to make org syntax links in any emacs buffer look like in org-mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166608/how-to-make-org-syntax-links-in-any-emacs-buffer-look-like-in-org-mode)

Answer (score 4):

I think text properties are what you are seeking.  The Elisp info file even includes an entry on "Clickable Text", Text -> Text Properties -> Clickable Text.  That section actually includes a pretty detailed example on how to achieve just the sort of thing you mention.

Comment: Thanks.  I have been working with text properties since I posted yesterday.  Making some progress, but not there yet. Many interactions with other packages. E.g.  org-open-at-point-global works fine in a non-org buffer, e.g. outline mode, but stops when there are properties you have defined yourself. I am still hoping that somebody has solved this in a generic way.

Comment: Now I am using org-open-link-from-string, so slowly am making progress.

Comment: OK, so I have the links mostly working.  Interaction with font-lock was a sticking point - it was preventing colors, etc., from being seen.  First I disabled font-lock, then I "borrowed" the face org-link, and used that.  Haven't yet made the ugly parts of a link invisible, but I am coloring the links and highlight when moused over.  Issues with mouse-1 and mouse-2 keybindings.  //  but, basically, well in my way.

Comment: I am heading towards a function "linkify-region", that accepts an an alist of match-functions (e.g. regexps), with corresponding functions to generate the link target, and the display name. Hiding the ugly parts; waffling on what to display, in case what to display is not actually text in the buffer.  // using org-open-link-from-string, to leverage as much org-mode goodness wrt link handling as possible, although it also has some badness.

Comment: Although I would still rather have found some already existing cide that does this rather than write my own from scratch (with the expected interference with other packages), I am marking this answered.  // But if anyone wants to say "Hey, idiot Glew, didn't you see the FOOBAR package that dies exactly what you want?" please tell me.

Comment: Hey selfish Glew, would you mind sharing your work ? :) I'm much much much interested. Thks !